# Expression language to set/get the value for a p:selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jstl

I have an two dimension array called timetable that stores the days and hours of the week. How do I provide an expression for the `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` value attribute to set/get the timetable values.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">  

    <h:panelGrid columns="24">  
        <c:forEach begin="0" end="6" varStatus="day">
            <c:forEach begin="0" end="23" varStatus="hour">  
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="...">  
                    <p:ajax listener="#{windowsLogonHours.selectHour(day.count - 1, hour.count - 1)}" />
                </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            </c:forEach>  
        </c:forEach>        
    </h:panelGrid>  
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `timetable` is a `boolean[][]`, then you can use [`LoopTagStatus#getIndex()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html#getIndex%28%29) from `varStatus` to get the iteration index which you can use as the index of the 2D array.

```html
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.timetable[day.index][hour.index]}">
```

Note that you must prepare the array yourself during backing bean's initialization or (post)construction. JSF/EL won't prepare the array for you, but only get/set its values by index.

Comment: The expression language for the value is correct. Only one small correction. The array must be Boolean[][]. At http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.2/p/selectBooleanCheckbox.html it says that value must evaluate to java.lang.Object.

Comment: I got this exception with boolean[][]: java.lang.ClassCastException: Unable to add an object of type [java.lang.Boolean] to an array of objects of type [boolean]

Comment: That's probably EL implementation specific. Are you using Tomcat? Does a single `boolean` property work fine for a single `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>` ?

Comment: Yes, I am using Tomcat 7. The <p:selectBooleanCheckbox> works fine with `boolean` property. At the moment I am using org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl

Comment: Tomcat 7 is known to have peculiar typechecking problems in EL like that (I wasn't aware of this particular one btw). Just keep it `Boolean[][]` then. You might want to post an issue report.